# Huge table over image crashes mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, html-table

I'm trying to create a worldmap that covers most of the screen while placing a table of ~10,000 cells of equal size over it.

Problem is that I guess the table is so big, that my mobile browsers die while trying to load it. The reason for such a big table is that I need ~10,000 cells to be able to clicked on and to show different images over the worldmap (images will be uploaded by people). So it should look like a huge montage after all.

Note: I know that this amount of cells will not look as nice as on desktop due to the high number of cells compared to the low number of pixels available.

Either I am obviously missing something (I haven't done anything like this and the first thing that came to my mind was that this is impossible), or this is really impossible.

The second image shows how it looks like on mobile after loading for 40 seconds. Before that everything was just a white canvas and the browser buttons were not tappable (iphone7, safari and chrome).

What I want to achieve

1. Table over worldmap
2. Users click on a cell, a modal comes in
3. Users upload an image of themselves
4. Modal closes
5. Uploaded image appears in the cell user clicked on

Any ideas?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Use an overlaying canvas, and calculate the correct modal to open with the coordinates of the click event. Another story is, how users can touch a specific spot on touchscreens when the spots are so small.

Comment: Showing the modal and doing the rest is easy. Showing the table over the image and not crashing the browser is the problem.

Comment: What ever, my message was: don't use a table, use a canvas.

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks! If you add it as an answer, I will accept it.